# In kendo auto completion how can I prevent user typing the field?

Tags: html, kendo-ui

Hi I am using an kendo auto complete for a text box. Where user can enter user input without choosing auto completion value. How can I prevent typing in in text box

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataSource: {
    data: ["One", "Two"]
  }
});
</script>
```

here is my code where user have one and two options

Comment: I am not sure if I understand question correctly, but if you want to let him choose from two values and not let type anything ... why it's not only dropdown?

Comment: i have a 100 list of array  for user its very difficult to check. So I am using auto complete

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom function and attach to onChange event.
Here is the example taken from Telerik page https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/autocomplete/how-to/input/restrict-user-input

```
$("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: data,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Select country...",
        change: function() {
          var found = false;
          var value = this.value();
          var data = this.dataSource.view();

          for(var idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
            if (data[idx] === value) {
              found = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!found) {
            this.value("");
            alert("Custom values are not allowed");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```